# I can only read one line of code out of my text file

Tags: android, readline

So I'm trying to make a todo list on Android where I can add items which then dynamically show in the list. So when I enter text in a text field and then press the add button, the list is expanded with the item I just created. This all goes well, but not if I completely get the application out of my memory stack and then restart it. When I reopen the application the list only consists of one item, the last item I added to the list before I closed the app. This is my code:

```
package be.oefeningen.filestorage;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;




public class FileStorageActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
    InputStream inputStream;
    String line;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String tekst=editText.getText().toString()+"\n";
        FileOutputStream outputStream;



        try {

            outputStream=openFileOutput("todoitems",MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(tekst.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            inputStream = openFileInput("todoitems");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line != null){
                values.add(line);
            } else {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            inputStream = openFileInput("todoitems");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                values.add(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
                inputStream.close();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_storage);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Comment: Prem's answer is correct... but you'd really want to use a database, not plaintext files.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but often the reading starts before the value has been written. So I need to turn my screen to get the correct values. I guess the slowness is one downside of these files.

Comment: Performance is the least of your problems. Why not use a database? SO much easier.

Comment: yeah, it was just an exercise. Not something to really use later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probable reason is, everytime you write to the file, you are losing the old data.

Replace this line

```
outputStream=openFileOutput("todoitems",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with this line

```
outputStream=openFileOutput("todoitems", MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
```